# Adding permission to User model in Django

Tags: django, permissions, contenttype

I'm trying to add a permission 'view_user' to User model in Django. I added a proxy model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Permission
from django.db import models


class RodanUser(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        permissions = (
            ('view_user', 'View User'),
        )
```

but I get the error :

```
ContentType matching query does not exist.
```

which in my opinion is because the app_label of Django's User is `auth` but app_label of RodanUser is `rodan`
So I changed the model and added app_label:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Permission


class RodanUser(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        permissions = (
            ('view_rodanuser', 'View User'),
        )
        app_label = 'auth'
```

now I get the error:

```
MixedContentTypeError at /users/
```

Strangest thing is that I actually was able to get this to work by first adding a none-proxy model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Permission
from django.db import models


class RodanUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('view_rodanuser', 'View Rodan User'),
        )
```

and then changing it into the proxy model from above(without the app_label) because the none-proxy model will add the permission in DB where the content_type_id points to RodanUser instead of User.

I found [this](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11154) which explains why I cannot use proxy with permission. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by using another approach: 
in `__init__.py` of my project I added:

```
@receiver(post_migrate)
def add_user_view_permissions(sender, **kwargs):
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='auth', model='user')
    Permission.objects.get_or_create(codename='view_user', name='View User', content_type=content_type)
```

Which adds the permission after migration.

Comment: is it the `__init__.py` of the django app (the one that has the same name as the django project) or the django project itself?